# lambda list to combine string

Tags: c#, string, list, lambda

Here is my table ,

```
myTable
-------------
id      name       age
-------------------------
1     NameOne       10
2     NameTwo       11
3     NameThree     12
4     NameFour      13  
5     NameFive      14
```

I retrieve my table likes ,

```
var _myList = DBContext.myTables.ToList();
```

I want to get string likes

```
"NameOne,NameTwo,NameThree,NameFour,NameFive"
```

How can I do this in shorter way ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `String.Join`

```
string names = String.Join(",", _myList.Select(x => x.Name));
```

Or you can even avoid loading other columns from DB:

```
string names = String.Join(",", DBContext.myTables.Select(x => x.Name));
```

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you want:

```
string names = string.Join(",", DBContext.myTable.Select(x => x.Name));
```

You don't need to go through an intermediate list - and in fact it's more efficient not to. With this query, *only* the names will be fetched from the database.

Comment: May I dare to correct one small mistake (big fan of Jon) :), you need to convert it into an Array, because string.Join expects a string array.

Comment: @bazz, actually there is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) that accepts `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @bazz: It depends on the version of .NET you're using. The overload list was significantly expanded in .NET 4.

Comment: @Andrei Really? Can you point me to some reference? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0.aspx)

Comment: @bazz: Look at the documentation you're pointing to - on the left side of the screen there's an overload list...

Answer (score 0):

```
var _myList = DBContext.myTables.ToList();
var names = _myList.Select(x => x.name);
var formattedStrings = string.Join(", ", names);
```